# How can I extract just a text from a different website and use it directly in my website

Tags: javascript

I realized that it is quite easy to use an hyperlink to extract and use an image in the website by using scr. I was wondering if I could do the same with a text using the class attribute. 
However I couldn't find a way which is as easy as for the image.

How can I do that that easily.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve?
Using an `<img src>` pointing to a different domain is „hotloading” the image.
The other domain could suspend your requests at any time.
Can't you copy&paste the text? (Respect Intellectual Property Rights here!)

Comment: The answer is no, there is no way to do that via an html tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get a particular HTML element from another page, it's not going to be as simple as setting the `src` for an image. Using `src` as in an image or an `iframe` works because you a referencing a static file, but if you're trying to pull something specific out of an HTML page, you will have to actually download the page and parse the results.

One way to accomplish this would be a combination of [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

```js
const domParse = new DOMParser();

fetch('https://www.cnn.com')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(page => {
    const pg = domParse.parseFromString(page, 'text/html');
    document.getElementById('other-page')
      .appendChild(pg.body);
});
```

```html
<div id="other-page"></div>
```

This won't work if cross-site scripting is blocked.